# Stored Procedure to obtain part of the records name from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, informix

Imagine that I have a table named "**TableA**" and this table has the columns **"IDtable", "Tabname" and "Suffix"**.

IDtable and Tabname are correctly filled, but the suffix has all the records null.

I have to develop a stored procedure which allows to fill the Suffix column. For that, I know that I have to filter the name of the records in tabname.

**Example:**

**Tabname:** a_type_price
**Suffix:** price

**Tabname:** a_d_ser_sales
**Suffix:** sales

I think that I have to develop a **for cycle**, which looks for the " _ " in the names of Tabname and filters everything after the last " _ ".

Anyone have any idea of the best way to perform this stored procedure?

Comment: A.R.R., your edit made the question harder to find and for future users to understand.  I've rolled it back.  Your suggested edit to my answer would also make the post far less useful to future users and I've rejected it.  Keep in mind that StackOverflow is a community, and the questions here are supposed to be for future readers at least as much as for the asker/answerer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to update  the table - you don't even really need a stored procedure unless this is something you ahve to run as a job or frequently.

You could do so like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Upd_TableASuffix() 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
UPDATE TableA SET Suffix = RIGHT(Tabname, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(Tabname)) - 1)
END
```

Quick explanation of that: You want the `RIGHT` part of the string after the last `_` character - to get the last one, use `CHARINDEX` on the `REVERSE` of the string.

You can't do this with a default constraint since you'd have to reference another column, but you could use a trigger, assuming `IDtable` is your primary key:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_TableA_Suffix
ON TableA
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE TableA SET Suffix = RIGHT(i.Tabname, CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(i.Tabname))-1)
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE TableA.IDTable = i.IDTable
GO
```

Note that this won't work if `IDTable` is non-unique, or if your table lacks a primary key entirely.

One last option - and this is probably the best if you really want `Suffix` to only ever contain the last part of `Tabname` and never want to change it - you could make `Suffix` a computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE TableA DROP COLUMN Suffix
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD Suffix AS RIGHT(Tabname, CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(Tabname))-1) PERSISTED
```

Answer (score 1):

For **informix**.

As @dan-field said, and explain, you can do the update using:

```
UPDATE tablea
SET suffix = RIGHT(tabname, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(tabname)) - 1);
```

Another way is:

```
UPDATE tablea
SET suffix = SUBSTR(tabname, INSTR(tabname, '_', -1)+1);
```

[INSTR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2336.htm?lang=en) will give you the index of the first occurrence  from the right (-1) of '*'. [SUBSTR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1561.htm?lang=en) will give you the substring starting from the index you pass, in this case we add 1 because we don't want the '*' to be outputted.

Bear in mind that [RIGHT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0271.htm?lang=en), [CHARINDEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0294.htm?lang=en), [REVERSE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0573.htm?lang=en) and [INSTR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2336.htm?lang=en) functions are only available from **11.70** onward.

On **11.50** you can try this ugly solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
    DEFINE i_IDtable LIKE tablea.IDtable;
    DEFINE c_suffix LIKE tablea.tabname;
    DEFINE i INT;

    FOREACH cur1 WITH HOLD FOR

        SELECT  IDtable ,Tabname
        INTO    i_IDtable, c_suffix
        FROM    tablea

        LET i = LENGTH(c_suffix);

        WHILE i > 0
            IF SUBSTR(c_suffix,i) LIKE '\_%' THEN
                LET c_suffix = SUBSTR(c_suffix,i+1);
                EXIT WHILE;
            ELSE
                LET i = i -1;
            END IF
        END WHILE;

        UPDATE tablea
        SET suffix = c_suffix,
        WHERE idtable = i_IDtable;

    END FOREACH;
END PROCEDURE;
```

But if suffix is always this part of the `tabname` it's not a good practice to store on the table.

You can easily get it from the already stored `tabname`. And even programmatically is easy to deal with it.